# Everything between anchor tag render's raw html tags in Jekyll/Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to build an include in Jekyll that has multiple variables, but the basic idea is that I'm wrapping multiple pieces of content in an anchor tag like the following:

```
<a href="#>
    <h2>{{ include.piece-title }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ include.piece-date }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ include.piece-url }}" alt="{{ include.image-description }}">
    <p>{{ include.piece-description }}</p>
</a>
```

However, this renders to the raw html (although the image works).

If I instead wrap it in a `<figure>` tag instead of the `<a>` tag, it doesn't have a problem. For example, this is fine:

```
<figure>
    <h2>{{ include.piece-title }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ include.piece-date }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ include.piece-url }}" alt="{{ include.image-description }}">
    <p>{{ include.piece-description }}</p>
</figure>
```

I can actually solve this by wrapping the `<a>` tags in other html like `<figure>` or `<div>` like the following, but this seems a bit overkill:

```
<figure>
    <a href="#">
        <h2>{{ include.piece-title }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ include.piece-date }}</h3>
        <img src="{{ include.piece-url }}" alt="{{ include.image-description }}">
        <p>{{ include.piece-description }}</p>
    </a>
</figure>
```

I've been searching high and low, but I can't find anything that references behavior like this except the [order of operations](https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/orderofinterpretation/). I can't seem to see where this would break the order though.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you have a repository url where you reproduce this behavior ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Wrapped the anchor in a div as a workaround